# Nginx - server static files

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I'm trying to configure nginx to serve static files (images).

I would like to get images by this URL:

> DOMAIN/images/RANDOM_FOLDER_NAME_123/RANDOM_FILE_NAME_456.png

On server I store images as:

> /usr/share/nginx/html/RANDOM_FOLDER_NAME_123/IMAGES
>   /usr/share/nginx/html/RANDOM_FOLDER_NAME_234/IMAGES
>   /usr/share/nginx/html/RANDOM_FOLDER_NAME_345/IMAGES
>   /usr/share/nginx/html/RANDOM_FOLDER_NAME_456/IMAGES

I would like to match fe.

```
DOMAIN/images/RANDOM_FOLDER_NAME_123/RANDOM_FILE_NAME_456.png -> /usr/share/nginx/html/RANDOM_FOLDER_NAME_123/RANDOM_FILE_NAME_456.png
```

How have I set nginx path to achieve this? I tried to do this by:

```
location /images/ {
     try_files $uri =404;
     autoindex off;    
}
```

But I think that problem is `images` in URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
location /images {
  alias /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
```

https://www.techcoil.com/blog/understanding-the-difference-between-the-root-and-alias-directives-in-nginx/